# Mobiscroll produces RangeError when in jquery dialog

Tags: mobiscroll

here is our code, we are using coffeescript, backbone, marionette and jquery for dialog. when the code executed the browser produces RangeError and freeze. has anyboy encounter same as our problem, can you help me to fix our problem.

thanks

```
onRender:->
        @showMobiscroll()
        if @options.value isnt undefined
          @$el.attr('value',@options.value)
        if @options.className isnt undefined
          @$el.addClass(@options.className)


    showMobiscroll:->
      ###
      @$el.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
      })
      ###
      @$el.mobiscroll().calendar({
        display:'bubble',
        theme:'mobiscroll'
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed the issue, just update on the latest jquery UI and latest jquery.